# Mysql not returning result as expected

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

Can anyone see what is wrong with this sql query.

This returns no results, although the same query out put so that vars are calculated and then run in mysql returns 3800+ results

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM twitter_user JOIN twitter_connection
          ON (twitter_user.tu_id = twitter_connection.tc_tu_id) 
          WHERE tc_followyou = 1 AND tc_twitterapp_user_id = ". $mytwitterid . " 
          LIMIT " . $perpage . " OFFSET " . $twitter_offset;
```

This same query however does work

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM twitter_user JOIN  twitter_connection 
          ON (twitter_user.tu_id = twitter_connection.tc_tu_id)
          WHERE tc_youfollow = 1 AND tc_twitterapp_user_id = ". $mytwitterid . " 
          LIMIT " . $perpage . " OFFSET " . $twitter_offset;
```

The only difference is the use of tc_followyou vs tc_youfollow

Both are in the same table, no NULL records, and integer.

If I take the exact same piece of php code adn swap tc_followyou for tc_youfollow I get a result.

I am not sure why, but this is only a problem if the script is run on an amazon RDS server Mysql v5.5.8-log, another server running mysql 5.1.52

works as expected.

Why would either the server version or the field name cause this issue?

I'm stumped.

Thanks Stephen

**UPDATE :** This is resolved. The issue was that the actual code I was running did not have a limit. I was carelessly running against the database to get a 'total'. This because the failing table had so many records, it did not return a result. I accepted the solution because the person helped me work through a thought process that helped discover the problem.

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages. Try to debug your SQL queries separately.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I've tried to do that and the query works fine directly in MYSQL. It's the execution through php5 to MYSQL that is not working and I can't for the life of me work out why.

Comment: Just in case, please hard-code the complete query inside a single-quoted string. You can also replace `*` with something like `COUNT(*) AS total` to discard other issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I did as you asked and ran this 'SELECT * FROM twitter_user LEFT JOIN twitter_connection ON (twitter_user.tu_id = twitter_connection.tc_tu_id) WHERE tc_followyou = 1 AND tc_twitterapp_user_id = 14630353' .... No result, in the script but worked in phpmyadmin :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` is unreliable if you don't use `ORDER BY` to provide a deterministic sort order. By design, the order of result rows is arbitrary unless you instruct SQL to sort them. That can specially affect the returned rows when you use a LIMIT clause.

Comment: Thank again, I get the same result even if I leave of the limit and offset.

Comment: You mention two servers. Are you sure they have the same data?

Comment: Yes, I actually exported data from the working server to the other to make sure. Both are dev servers, and both are using the same storage engine (InnoDB)

Comment: I've added a note to the answer to say the problem with my code was that a predecessor was trying to get a total number of records and it was trying to return all records to an array. A careless piece of trial code from development that got through :-)